# Jenkins stalls after selenium server is started

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run automated tests in Jenkins. The tests had been running well for a long time. But now, when selenium server starts the tests, Jenkins stalls and outputs the following error messages:

```
   [09:18:55] E/launcher - Unable to parse new session response: 
   [09:18:55] E/launcher - WebDriverError: Unable to parse new session 
   response: 
   at doSend.then.response..."
```

The tests run successfully when I run them manually at the command prompt using the same commands. I am not sure what could be the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
You may be using old version of chrome with a newer Selenium WebDriver version. You may want to update your chrome to the latest version.

**Solution 2:**
Multiple versions of Chrome may have been installed. Purge and install a stable package. Do something like:

```
sudo apt-get purge chrome
sudo apt-get install chrome-stable
```

**Solution 3:**
Reinstall your JDK. This is a sure fire way to revive sleeping Jenkins.